# Finding sum of unique items from one column for row values of a another column

Tags: python, pandas, unique

So let's say I have this table:

| city | store_number |
| --- | --- |
| NY | 1 |
| NY | 1 |
| NY | 2 |
| CH | 1 |
| CH | 2 |
| CH | 3 |
| CH | 3 |

How can I count the total number of unique stores for each city? So it would display something like this:

| city | unique_store |
| --- | --- |
| NY | 2 |
| CH | 3 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
out = (
    df.groupby('city', as_index=False, sort=False)
    .agg(unique_store=('store_number', 'nunique'))
)
```

Gives you:

```
  city  unique_store
0   NY             2
1   CH             3
```